# mongodb $nin not work in php

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

Current Code:

```
$doc = array('ooxx' => array(1,2,3,4,5));

datamodel()->insert($doc);

$doc2 = array('ooxx' => array(6,7,8,9));
datamodel()->insert($doc2);

$macher = array('ooxx'=>array('$exists' => true), 'ooxx' => array('$nin'=>array(6)));
$res = datamodel()->findOne($macher);
print_r($res);
```

When I **replace** the `$macher` with bellow, it does work well, why? is this a bug of mongodb?

```
$macher = array( 'ooxx' => array('$nin'=>array(6)), 'ooxx'=>array('$exists' => true));
```

Comment: $nin does work in php. did u see any errors returned from the query ? Log the result of the query and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because the keys have the same name and one overwrites the other. So the "keys" need to be unique.

If you have two conditions for the same key you use the [**`$and`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) operator which takes an array of arguments:

```
$matcher = array(
    '$and' => array( 
        array( 'ooxx' => array( '$nin' => array(6) ) ),
        array( 'ooxx' => array( '$exists' => true ) )
    )
)
```

Or for the JSON minded:

```js
{
    "$and": [
        { "ooxx": { "$nin": [6] } },
        { "ooxx": { "$exists": true } }
    ]
}
```

Which is a valid structure where what you are writing is not.